# Is it ok to use Headings beyond H6 in HTML and CSS?

Tags: html, css, html-heading

Headings have always been H1 to H6, but what about H7, H8...H137, ect.  To my surprise, they all work!.  You can style any heading number any way you want.  I tried them in several modern browsers and had no problems.  Why would I want to use them, you ask....  Well, instead of typing something like `<span class="h7">Hello World</span>`  I could just type `<h7>Hello world</h7>` and get the same result.  Is there a write up on this anywhere?  Is it wrong to do this?  Are there browsers newer than IE8 that don't support it?

Comment: Six levels of heading should be enough for anyone. If you have a genuine use case for more levels, you should present as an issue at https://github.com/w3c/html/issues

Answer (score 2):

No. Only the first 6 are standard.

[**The `h1`, `h2`, `h3`, `h4`, `h5`, and `h6` elements**](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-h1,-h2,-h3,-h4,-h5,-and-h6-elements)

Note there is no need for additional ones, because they represent headings for their sections. So instead of using headers with lower rank, you can use nested sections.

> As far as their respective document outlines (their heading and section structures) are concerned, these two snippets are semantically equivalent:
>
> ```html
> <body>
>   <h1>Let's call it a draw(ing surface)</h1>
>   <h2>Diving in</h2>
>   <h2>Simple shapes</h2>
>   <h2>Canvas coordinates</h2>
>   <h3>Canvas coordinates diagram</h3>
>   <h2>Paths</h2>
> </body>
> ```
>
> ```html
> <body>
>   <h1>Let's call it a draw(ing surface)</h1>
>   <section>
>     <h1>Diving in</h1>
>   </section>
>   <section>
>     <h1>Simple shapes</h1>
>   </section>
>   <section>
>     <h1>Canvas coordinates</h1>
>     <section>
>       <h1>Canvas coordinates diagram</h1>
>     </section>
>   </section>
>   <section>
>     <h1>Paths</h1>
>   </section>
> </body>
> ```

Comment: "semantically equivalent" Yeah maybe. But accessibility tools won't treat them the same, and for that reason the latest HTML 5 drafts advise against the practice, so we should discourage it too.

Answer (score 1):

The main purpose of headings is their semantics, as they indicate short and important parts of the website, which screenreader users my use to get a quick overview about the website content and navigate through it. Especially the latter is important for screenreader-users.

As h1-h6 indicate different importance and as a basic rule you should try to use as few levels as possible (h1-h3, h4 at max), it makes no sense using h7-hxxx.

**h7-hxxx are no valid html heading elements and just because browers try to interpret them as semantic-less `div`s without breaking, it doesn't mean, that they "work". They do NOT, as they have no semantics**

TLDR: Definitely do NOT use them.

edit: you mentioned, that IE9+ don't "break". This is mainly because of html5, which causes browsers to interpret unkown elements as meaning- and semanticless elements (like normal `div`s).

Answer (score 1):

It's not maybe according to standards, but you can define your own elements. It's not related with h7-h200, but with any word. You can use e.g. `blabla` or `houhouhou`. Code here:

```
<style type="text/css">
    houhouhou   {color: green}
    blabla { color: blue}
</style>

<houhouhou>Hello</houhouhou>
<blabla>World</blabla>
```

[Code for testing here.](https://jsfiddle.net/wrmp5sn5/)

But as others, I also recommend to use classic css classes with `div` or `span` in this spirit:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .houhouhou   {color: green}
    .blabla { color: blue}
</style>

<div class="houhouhou">Hello</div>
<div class="blabla">World</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Having custom tags such as `<h7></h7>` will be treated as an inline div element and will render but I'd advise against it because they are non-standard tags for describing header hierarchy, so screen readers and parsers might not make sense of it. Stick to using standard semantic elements for header tags. Having a really deep hierarchy of header tags usually indicates a problem with how you're semantically structuring the layout.

Answer (score 0):

Html specs specify heading tags between H1 and H6 (inclusive). Anything beyond that could potentially work within browsers as anticipated, but since it is not a part of html specifications, browser can interpret however they want (perhaps differently), so I would not totally rely on it. That would apply to anything that is not part of html specifications. However, H tags are quite straight forward to understand, thus I believe browser should interpret those tags above H6 correctly and in similar fashion.

Comment: "I believe browser should interpret those tags above H6 correctly and in similar fashion." They won't. They'll parse differently, style differently, and most importantly, will be presented to accessibility APIs differently,

Comment: I said similar, not the same